# lazyloading without using lazy<t>

Tags: c#

I have:

Category class

```
 public partial class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        ...
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private ICollection<Discount> _appliedDiscounts;
        public virtual ICollection<Discount> AppliedDiscounts
        {
            get { return _appliedDiscounts ?? (_appliedDiscounts = new List<Discount>()); }
            protected set { _appliedDiscounts = value; }
        }
}
```

Service:

```
public IList<Category> GetCategories()
{
   // ado.net to return category entities.

}
public ICollection<Discount> GetDiscount(int categoryId)
{
   // ado.net .

}
```

I don't want to use ORM like EF.. but plain ado.net and i don't want to put in ugly `Lazy<T>` in my domain definition, for e.g public Lazy....

So how in this case could I get AppliedDiscounts automatically get binded lazy to GetDiscount without using explicitly declaration of `Lazy<T>` on the Category class ?

Comment: What's the point in lazily creating an empty list?  I see no real need to defer doing that.  Now if you were say populating the list with the results of a database query, then *that* is worth deferring.

Comment: If you are not using ORM, then whats the point of using `Lazy`? You can fetch whenever you want. People usually uses lazy so that ORM does not make unnecessary joins.

Comment: In what context are you using this? A console app, a web app, a desktop app... the way one does lazy loading does change depending on this...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you don't like the `Lazy<T>` type - it is simple, useful and you don't have to worry about anything.

And no one forces you to use `public Lazy<IEnumerable<Discount>> GetDiscounts();`

You could use it internally:

```
Lazy<IEnumerable<Discount>> discounts = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Discount>>(() => new DiscountCollection());

public IEnumerable<Discount> GetDiscounts()
{
   return discounts.Value;
}
```

It operates as intended - until no one asks for discounts it won't be created.

If you really want - you could create your own implementation. Something like Singleton class in Richter's "CLR via C#" book (because Lazy has all the 'properties' of a proper singleton container - thread safety, only one instance of inner 'singleton' value could be evaluated...).

But do you really want to create it and test? You will just replace a well-designed standard component with a fishy custom one.

**AFTER ACTUALLY READING YOUR QUESTION WITH ATTENTION**

1) If your lazy loading does not need any thread safety you could accomplish similar behaviour even without any Lazy or complex constructs - just use Func delegate:

```
public partial class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        ...
        private Func<ICollection<Discount>> getDiscounts;

        public Category(Func<ICollection<Discount>> getDiscounts) { ... }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        private ICollection<Discount> _appliedDiscounts;
        public virtual ICollection<Discount> AppliedDiscounts
        {
            get { return _appliedDiscounts ??
 (_appliedDiscounts = new List<Discount>(this.getDiscounts())); }
            protected set { _appliedDiscounts = value; }
        }
}

public IList<Category> GetCategories()
{
   // ado.net to return category entities.
   ... = new Category(() => this.GetDiscount((Int32)curDataObject["categoryId"]))

}
public ICollection<Discount> GetDiscount(int categoryId)
{
   // ado.net .
}
```

If you inject your service it will be even more simple:

```
        public virtual ICollection<Discount> AppliedDiscounts
        {
            get { return _appliedDiscounts ?? 
(_appliedDiscounts = new List<Discount>(this.service.GetDiscounts(this.CategoryId))); }
            protected set { _appliedDiscounts = value; }
        }
```

2) If you need to use these objects in multiple threads then you will have to redesign your classes - they don't look like threadsafe.

**AFTER THE COMMENT**

> what i want to do is exactly just like this guy
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/8188546/… . I want to know the concept how
>   ORM like EF do with the domain, keep it clean and separated from
>   injecting service class but still able to handle lazy loading. I know
>   i can use Reflection to get all the object properties and its object
>   variables(like AppliedDiscounts), but dont' know how to transform
>   these dynamically to lazy type so that it could be loaded later when
>   needed.

It is universal principle that you can't get something for nothing. You can't make your entities both clean and separated from any services(even through some proxy), and to allow them to load lazily - if they don't know anything about services and services don't know anything about them then how would the lazy loading work? There is no way to achieve such absolute decoupling(for two components to interact they have to either know about each other, know about some third module-communicator, or some module should know about them. But such coupling could be partially or completely hidden.

Technologies that provide entity object models usually use some of the following techniques:

1. Code generation to create wrappers(or proxies) above your simple data objects, or solid instances of your interfaces. It could be C# code or IL weaving, well, it could be even an in-memory assembly created dynamically in runtime using something like Reflection.Emit. This is not the easiest or most direct approach, but it will give you enormous code-tuning capabilities. A lot of modern frameworks use it.
2. Implementation of all those capabilities in Context classes - you won't have the lazy loading in your end objects, you will have to use it explicitly with Context classes: `context.Orders.With("OrderDetails")`. The positive side is that the entities will be clean.
3. Injection of service(or only of the needed subset of its operations) - that's what you'd prefer to avoid.
4. Use of events or some other observer-like pattern - your entities
   will be clean from service logic and dependencies(at least in some
   sense), but will contain some hookup infrastructure that won't be
   very straightforward or easy to manage.

For your custom object model 2 or 3 are the best bets.  But you could try 1 with [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That won't compile; it's not a valid constructor parameter for `Lazy`.

Comment: thanks eugene for taking your time to help me. Actually, what i want to do is exactly just like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188546/irepository-aggregates-and-lazy-loading . I want to know the concept how ORM like EF do with the domain, keep it clean and separated from injecting service class but still able to handle lazy loading. I know i can use Reflection to get all the object properties and its object variables(like AppliedDiscounts), but dont' know how to transform these dynamically to lazy type so that it could be loaded later when needed.